How to create an .img from a LVM Logical Volume
I have some LVM logical volumes in a machine, and I would like to create backup images (.img) stored in another machine.

Most volumes are LVM-Thin, and I cannot resize the volumes before creating the images. Then, how to keep the image files as small as possible?
Is dd capable of creating a thin image of a volume?
In addition to dd, which other tools can I use for this task?


research "backing up lvm volumes"
